# Does this Token Based Authentication System design make any sense?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt, token, spring-security-oauth2

We have to build an external authentication system that can ba used for most of our softwares.
This is the sequence diagram I built: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tboAv.png

The flow goes like this:

1. MP (Angular) makes a TOKEN request (username, ...)
2. The authentication service processes the given data, generates a token and sends it     back to MP (Angular)
3. MP (Angular) sends a request (a CRUD operation for example), MP (Spring Boot) only checks the expiration date of the token and sends the response back to the client

Do you think this makes any sense? I'm not sure about the part where MP (Spring Boot) checks the expiration date. I've never built an external Authentication System so feel free to criticize my design.

Comment: _Don't_ write your own authentication system. Use a standard one, such as the OAuth2 you mentioned in your tags. (The recommended OAuth2 flow for your case is "authorization code with PKCE".)

Comment: Or even something like `Keycloak` and your job would be already done. Deploy, configure and enjoy. Reinventing the wheel is great if you want to learn, but something tells me this is just work.